# How to login Facebook using nested fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-fragments

I have nested fragment like the following.

- MainActivity

  - FragmentA

    - FragmentA1

      - FragmentA3
    - FragmentA2
  - FragmentB

    - FragmentB1

I want to login facebook from FragmentA3. But can not.

In FragmentA3, my app stop in onResume after called onActivityResult.

What should I do?

*FragmentA3*

```
public class FragmentA3 extends Fragment {

  public static final String TAG = FragmentA3.class.getCanonicalName();
  private UiLifecycleHelper mFbSdkUiHelper;
  private OnLoggedListener mCallback;
  private final List<String> permissions;

  public OthersFBLogin() {
      // Required empty public constructor
      permissions = Arrays.asList("basic_info", "email");
  }

  public interface OnLoggedListener {
      //Callback to notify about login success.
      public void onLoginSuccess();
  }

  private final Session.StatusCallback mSessionCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
      @Override
      public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
      }
  };

  private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
      Log.d(TAG,"onSessionStateChange");
      if (state.isOpened()) {
          mCallback.onLoginSuccess();
      } else if (state.isClosed()) {
          if (session != null) {
              session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
          }
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      Log.d(TAG,"onCreate");
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      mFbSdkUiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), mSessionCallback);
      mFbSdkUiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      Log.d(TAG,"onCreateView");
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.others_fblogin, container, false);
      LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
      loginButton.setFragment(this);
      loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissions);

      return rootView;
  }

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
      Log.d(TAG,"onAttach");
      super.onAttach(activity);
      try {
          mCallback = (OnLoggedListener) activity;
      } catch (ClassCastException e) {
          throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                  + " must implement OnLoggedListener in order to use this fragment");
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
      Log.d(TAG,"onResume");
      super.onResume();
      Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
      if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
          onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
      }
      mFbSdkUiHelper.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroyView() {
      super.onDestroyView();
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      Log.d(TAG,"onActivityResult");
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      mFbSdkUiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
      Log.d(TAG,"onPause");
      super.onPause();
      mFbSdkUiHelper.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      mFbSdkUiHelper.onDestroy();
  }

  @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      Log.d(TAG,"onSaveInstanceState");
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
      mFbSdkUiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  }
}
```

*LogCat*

```
D/com.example.sample.FragmentA3  ﹕ onAttach
D/com.example.sample.FragmentA3  ﹕ onCreate
D/com.example.sample.FragmentA3  ﹕ onCreateView
D/com.example.sample.FragmentA3  ﹕ onResume
D/dalvikvm                       ﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 764K, 10% free 7977K/8816K, paused 3ms, total 6ms
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil         ﹕ Google Play services is missing.
D/com.example.sample.FragmentA3  ﹕ onPause
D/com.example.sample.FragmentA3  ﹕ onSessionStateChange
W/EGL_emulation                  ﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
I/Choreographer                  ﹕ Skipped 174 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/com.example.sample.MainActivity﹕ onActivityResult
D/com.example.sample.FragmentA   ﹕ onActivityResult
D/com.example.sample.FragmentA3  ﹕ onActivityResult
D/com.example.sample.FragmentA3  ﹕ onResume
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution:

```
public class FragmentA3 extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       Fragment fragmentA1 = this.getParentFragment();
       Fragment fragmentA = fragmentA1.getParentFragment();

      loginButton.setFragment(fragmentA);
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      Log.d(TAG,"onActivityResult");
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      mFbSdkUiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
}

public class FragmentA1 extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if (mFragmentA3 !=null)
         mFragmentA3.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
}

public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if (mFragmentA1 !=null)
         mFragmentA1.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add the below code in the fragment.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){
 context = getContext();
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(context);
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facebook_sign_in, container, false);
}
```

Step 2: Handle the callback of facebook.

```
  private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        try {
                            String email = object.getString("email");
                            String firstName = object.getString("first_name");
                            String lastName = object.getString("last_name");
                            profile_link = object.getString("link");
                            String profilePicUrl = object.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                            Utility.logMe("\nFacebook_user_mail:"+email +"\nFacebook_user_Fname:"+firstName+"\nFacebook_user_Lname:"+lastName+"\nFacebook_user_Image:"+profilePicUrl+"\nProfile_link:"+profile_link);
                            if(email != null && email.length()> 0)
                            {
                                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                                signUpFacebook(firstName, lastName, email, profilePicUrl, profile_link);
                            }

                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Email not present to login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Email Not Exist for this user on Facebook.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());

                        }

                    }
                });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,link,name,email,birthday,gender,first_name,last_name,picture.type(large)");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

    }
```

Step 3:

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    accessTokenTracker= new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

        }
    };

    profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
            //displayMessage(newProfile);
        }
    };

    accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
    profileTracker.startTracking();
}
```

Step 4:

```
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);

}
```

Step 5:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Step 6:

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    List<Fragment> allFragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    for (Fragment fragmento : allFragments) {
        if (fragmento instanceof TwitterSignIn) {
            ((TwitterSignIn) fragmento).onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
        if (fragmento instanceof GooglePlusSignIn) {
            ((GooglePlusSignIn) fragmento).onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
        if (fragmento instanceof FacebookSignIn) {
            ((FacebookSignIn) fragmento).onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```